# Error while installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, composer-php

While installing the friends of `Symfony` user bundle, I came across this error. Can someone help me solve this issue?

```
Ahmeds-MBP:placementlink2 ahmed$ composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle 
Using version ^2.1 for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle 
./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev) Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1 
- Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.2 
- Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.1 
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.5.0 
- Conclusion: remove twig/twig v1.23.1 
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v2.4.8 
- Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^2.1 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2]. 
- Conclusion: don't install twig/twig v1.23.1 
- friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.0 requires twig/twig ^1.28 || ^2.0 -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.28.0, v1.28.1, v1.28.2, v1.29.0, v1.30.0, v1.31.0, v1.32.0, v1.33.0, v1.33.1, v1.33.2, v1.34.0, v1.34.1, v1.34.2, v1.34.3, v1.34.4, v1.35.0, v1.35.1, v1.35.2, v1.35.3, v1.35.4, v2.0.0, v2.1.0, v2.2.0, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.2, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.5.0]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.28.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.28.1, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.28.2, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.29.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.30.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.31.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.32.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.33.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.33.1, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.33.2, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.1, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.2, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.3, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.34.4, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.1, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.2, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.3, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v1.35.4, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.0.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.1.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.2.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.3.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.3.1, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.3.2, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.0, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.1, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.2, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.3, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.4, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.5, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.6, v1.23.1]. 
- Can only install one of: twig/twig[v2.4.7, v1.23.1]. 
- Installation request for twig/twig (locked at v1.23.1) -> satisfiable by twig/twig[v1.23.1].

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

and this is my composer.json file:

```
"require":{  
  "php":">=5.5.9",
  "symfony/symfony":"3.0.*",
  "doctrine/orm":"^2.5",
  "doctrine/doctrine-bundle":"^1.6",
  "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle":"^1.2",
  "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle":"^2.3",
  "symfony/monolog-bundle":"^2.8",
  "sensio/distribution-bundle":"^5.0",
  "sensio/framework-extra-bundle":"^3.0.2",
  "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler":"^2.0"
},
"require-dev":{  
  "sensio/generator-bundle":"^3.0",
  "symfony/phpunit-bridge":"^2.7"
},
```

Comment: Can you please post the contents of your `composer.json`?

Comment: To me this looks like some nasty upgrade dependency conflict. Is this a new installation or an upgrade?

Comment: could you please explain what you mean by nasty upgrade dependency conflict.

Comment: I can, but first I need to know if this is in fact a new installation of Symfony?

Comment: yeah it is a new installation

Comment: Alright, so it is not an upgrade conflict. Can you try upgrading your `twig/twig` first? Just run `composer update twig/twig`...

Comment: I got this error after running this command [Twig_Error_Runtime]                  
  The "core" extension is not enabled.             

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception                               
  [RuntimeException]                                                         
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:  
                           
    [Twig_Error_Runtime]                                     
    The "core" extension is not enabled.

Comment: This turns out the be a known bug. Can you elaborate on why were you installing 3.0 as it is not supported for quite some time now already?

Comment: I have changed the version of symfony from 3.0.* to 3.1.* and ran the command composer update twig/twig again and it updated successfully and when i tried to install friends of symfony bundle again its now having different error

Comment: Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.1
    - Conclusion: remove paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ^2.1 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.2].
    - Conclusion: don't install paragonie/random_compat v9.99.99
    - friendsofsymfony/user-bundle v2.1.0 requires paragonie/random_compat ^1 || ^2 ->

Comment: Please update the question instead and please keep it formatted...

Answer (score 0):

I did a little of googling for the [**issue**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/20284) that you mentioned above and there seems to be is a bugfix for it. Unfortunately, as far as I understood, the fix was not ported to 3.0 release as, at the time of the bug, 3.0 was no longer maintained:

> **Fabien Potencier (fabpot) commented on Oct 23, 2016**
>
> Oh, I see that you are using `Symfony 3.0`. It won't work unfortunately as `3.0` is not maintained anymore. You need to either upgrade to `3.1` or use `Twig 1.x`.

Please proceed as Fabien suggested and you should probably get rid of an issue.

Hope this helps...